# Discord reaction roles issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am currently coding a discord bot reaction roles command.

Everything is running smoothly but I have one issue.

When I boot the bot and run the command to create the embed, everything works fine. The issue is when I react to the message it doesn't give me the role. Here is my code:

```js
module.exports = {
    name: "reactionrole",
    description: "Sets up a reaction role message!",
    async execute(message, args, Discord, client) {
        const channel = "751217304733351976";
        const yellowTeamRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find((role) => role.name === "ROBLOX");
        const blueTeamRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find((role) => role.name === "Minecraft");
        const redTeamRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find((role) => role.name === "MinecraftBedrock");

        const yellowTeamEmoji = "798904223755927562";
        const blueTeamEmoji = "798904030553440257";
        const redTeamEmoji = "798904121544540181";

        let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor("#e42643")
            .setTitle("Choose the games you play!")
            .setDescription("Choosing a game will ping you when others want to play with you!\n\n" + `ROBLOX\n` + `Minecraft\n` + "Minecraft Bedrock");

        let messageEmbed = await message.channel.send(embed);
        messageEmbed.react(yellowTeamEmoji);
        messageEmbed.react(blueTeamEmoji);
        messageEmbed.react(redTeamEmoji);

        client.on("messageReactionAdd", async (reaction, user) => {
            if (reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();
            if (reaction.partial) await reaction.fetch();
            if (user.bot) return;
            if (!reaction.message.guild) return;

            if (reaction.message.channel.id == channel) {
                if (reaction.emoji.name === yellowTeamEmoji) {
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(yellowTeamRole);
                }
                if (reaction.emoji.name === blueTeamEmoji) {
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(blueTeamRole);
                }
                if (reaction.emoji.name === redTeamEmoji) {
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(redTeamRole);
                } else {
                    return;
                }
            }
        });

        client.on("messageReactionRemove", async (reaction, user) => {
            if (reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();
            if (reaction.partial) await reaction.fetch();
            if (user.bot) return;
            if (!reaction.message.guild) return;

            if (reaction.message.channel.id == channel) {
                if (reaction.emoji.name === yellowTeamEmoji) {
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove(yellowTeamRole);
                }
                if (reaction.emoji.name === blueTeamEmoji) {
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove(blueTeamRole);
                }
                if (reaction.emoji.name === redTeamEmoji) {
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove(redTeamRole);
                } else {
                    return;
                }
            }
        });
    },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it give a 0 exit error?

Also  check if the Bot's Role is above the Red, blue and yellow role on the role list

Comment: It does not. And the bot role is the highest in the server.

Comment: The names of the roles are 

ROBLOX,
Minecraft,
Minecraft Bedrock,

In the discord server.

Answer (score 0):

There are two places where you can grab emojis using discord.js: in the client, and in the guilds. `client.emojis` is a collection of every emoji the client has access to, and `guild.emojis` is a collection of the emojis of a specific guild.

```
const yellowTeamEmoji = client.emojis.get("798904223755927562")
```

You might also know how to use `find` to get something with another property - so here, I can get `yellowTeamEmoji` through its name:

```
const yellowTeamEmoji = client.emojis.find(emoji => emoji.name === "yellowTeamEmoji");
```

All the best, Florian.

Answer (score 0):

So what you need to do is:

```
    const reactionEmoji = client.emojis.cache.get("emojiID");
    const reactionEmoji2 = client.emojis.cache.get("emojiID");
    const reactionEmoji3 = client.emojis.cache.get("emojiID");

    const yellowTeamEmoji = "reactionEmoji1";
    const blueTeamEmoji = "reactionEmoji2";
    const redTeamEmoji = "reactionEmoji3";
```

How to get id of emojis ? The easiest way is to send ,in a test channel, the emoji that you want to set and if you right click on the emoji, at the bottom , it's says "OPEN LINK" . If you open that link in your browser it will show something like this : "https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/791979565056000000.png?v=1"
You need to copy the numbers in the end and paste is in the section "emojiID"

example:

```
const reactionEmoji = client.emojis.cache.get("791979565056000000");
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of ID use unicode. Just post the emoji in the channel, copy it and paste it in your code.

```
const yellowTeamEmoji = "";
```